# What is the value of $|\psi\chi|^2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spinors

I have been learning about spin. I see several authors write the total state function (including spin) as $\psi(r_1,r_2)\chi_{s,m_s}$. Is this understood to be the tensor product $\psi(r_1,r_2)\chi_{s,m_s} = \psi(r_1,r_2)\otimes\chi_{s,m_s}$? I am asking because I am trying to work out the value of $|\psi(r_1,r_2)\chi_{s,m_s}|^2$. I thought one interpretation could be
$$
|\psi(r_1,r_2)\chi_{s,m_s}|^2 = |\psi(r_1,r_2) \otimes \chi_{s,m_s}|^2 = (\psi(r_1,r_2) \otimes \chi_{s,m_s})^*(\psi(r_1,r_2) \otimes \chi_{s,m_s})= (\psi(r_1,r_2)^* \otimes {\chi_{s,m_s}}^*)(\psi(r_1,r_2) \otimes \chi_{s,m_s}) = |\psi(r_1,r_2)|^2\|\chi_{s,m_s}\|_\chi^2,
$$
for a suitable choice of norm $\|\cdot\|_\chi$. If this is indeed the correct idea, what is the definition of $\|\cdot\|_\chi$? If it is the wrong idea, how is  $|\psi(r_1,r_2)\chi_{s,m_s}|^2$ determined?

Comment: "Is this understood to be the tensor product?" Yes. The norm of a spinor is defined the usual way. For example, the spin up state $|\uparrow \rangle$ has norm $1$, the spin down state $|\downarrow \rangle$ also has norm $1$, and superpositions of the two obey the usual rules.

Comment: @knzhou Thank you! How would you evaluate something like $| \uparrow \downarrow + \downarrow \uparrow |^2$?

Comment: Should formally be $\vert \vert \uparrow\rangle\vert \downarrow \rangle + \vert \downarrow\rangle\vert \uparrow \rangle \vert^2 = 2 $ if the individual spin states $\vert \uparrow\rangle$ and $\vert \downarrow \rangle$ are normalized so that $\Vert \vert a b\rangle \Vert^2 =\Vert \vert a\rangle \Vert^2 \Vert \vert b\rangle \Vert^2$

Comment: @ZeroTheHero For the first equality, how do you deal with nonlinearity of the norm?

Comment: $|\uparrow\rangle\otimes|\downarrow\rangle$ and $|\downarrow\rangle\otimes|\uparrow\rangle$ are orthogonal, so nonlinearity doesn't play any role here.